# Use model's function in query/annotation?

Tags: django, django-models, annotations, django-orm

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
class User(models.Model):

    ...

    def is_available(self, param=None):
        # some logic here
        return True/False
```

And the I want to filter according to this model's method

```
    User.objects.annotate(available=is_available()).filter(available=True)
```

Obviously the line above is not valid, but is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: Why not make a `@property`, e.g. `available`, that calls (or just is) `is_available`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe will that work? I edited the question, my function takes an optional parameter.

Comment: But if you're not using that in the call for `annotate`, just let it take the default value. Or is that not representative either?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope. Using `is_available` as a field, is not working, that's not a field choice.

Comment: No, you have to make it a *property*

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did. Once it's a property, how should I use it a query?